# Firebase what should I do after idToken expires

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I'm using `onAuthStateChanged`:

```
this.unregisterAuthObserver = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    user.getIdToken(true).then((idToken) => {
      console.log(user)
      ...
    });
  }
```

When logged user becomes idle for 1hour `idToken` expires. What should I do after `idToken` expires? Trying to show some UI to users. Show modal to let the user know that session expired? or maybe reload page `location.reload()`?

Also is it possible to get `idToken` expiration time? `console.log(user)` doesn't get me expiration time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use onIdTokenChanged().  As described in the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged):

> Adds an observer for changes to the signed-in user's ID token, which
> includes sign-in, sign-out, and token refresh events.

The token refresh events are what you're interested in.

But you don't need to do anything when the token expires.  Firebase Authentication will [refresh it for you automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49697718), seamlessly.