# Do I need to get the User Token each and every time from the Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I have put the below method on the `Auth` service and get the `currentUserIdToken` and store it as a global variable. Is this approach has any issues? i.e. will it expire this token quickly or something like that? Or do I need to get this each and every time from the Firebase? I have done this kind of approach since I can avoid unnecessary calls to the db. Any thoughts?

```
init(): void {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(async (user: firebase.User) => {
      if (user) {
        this.currentUserUid = user.uid;
      this.currentUserIdToken = await this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true); // Here

        this.onboardingService.currentUserUid = this.currentUserUid;


    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token will expire every hour.  Instead of making a call to `getIdToken()` repeatedly, you can listen for changes to it using [onIdTokenChanged()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#on-idtoken-changed) and provide a callback to receive the new token immediately when it's automatically refreshed by the client SDK.

See also:

- [Is the firebase access token refreshed automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49656489/is-the-firebase-access-token-refreshed-automatically)

Comment: Can I have an `AngularFireAuth` method for it? It seems there is no such thing no?

Comment: Did you try searching the documentation?  It's just a wrapper around the core Firebase library.  If you don't find it, then file an issue on the angularfire GitHub.

Comment: Yes, it has `this.afAuth.idToken`